# Python Script skips process of Shell Script file

Tags: python, linux, shell

I'm trying to automate the deletion of a program with python and shell scripts.
this is the code I use to execute my shell scripts.

```
import subprocess

self.shellscript = subprocess.Popen([self.shellScriptPath], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE )
self.shellscript.stdin.write('yes\n'.encode("utf-8"))
self.shellscript.stdin.close()
self.returncode = self.shellscript.wait()
```

This is the shell script that I want to run.

```
echo *MY PASSWORD* | sudo -S apt-get --purge remove *PROGRAM*
echo *MY PASSWORD* | sudo -S apt-get autoremove
echo *MY PASSWORD* | sudo -S apt-get clean
```

I know it's not secure to code my password into it like this but I will fix this later.

My problem is that the commandline asks me to type `y/n` but the program skips that and nothing happens.

Comment: The simple fix is to use the `-y` option of `apt-get`. More generally, prefer `subprocess.run` over `subprocess.Popen`; notice the `input` keyword argument.

Comment: You cant (easily) use a list of arguments with `shell=True`; unless you _really_ know what you are doing, use either `subprocess.run('command with args', shell=True)` (but understand the [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)) or `subprocess.run(['command', 'with', 'arguments])` with no `shell`.

Comment: that works perfectly but only if I remove the last three lines self.shellscript.stdin.write('yes\n'.encode("utf-8")),
self.shellscript.stdin.close(),
self.returncode = self.shellscript.wait() I became the error self.shellscript has no attribute stdin. Should i worry about it?

Comment: One of the many reasons to prefer `subprocess.run` is that it replaces _all of_ your code with a single call. `self.returncode = subprocess. run(self.shellScriptPath, input='yes\n', text=True).returncode` (though the `self.` is dubious here; take it out if this isn't inside a method of a class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the absolutely simplest fix is to use

```
apt-get -y ...
```

and do away with passing input to the command entirely.

In the general case, you want to avoid `Popen` in every scenario where you can.  You are reimplementing `subprocess.call()` but not doing it completely.  Your entire attempt can be reduced to (and fixed with)

```py
self.returncode = subprocess.run(
    self.shellScriptPath, input='yes\n', text=True).returncode
```

Unless the commands in `self.shellScriptPath` require a shell, probably remove `shell=True` and, if necessary, `shlex.split()` the value into a list of tokens (though if it's already a single token, just split it yourself, trivially: `[self.shellScriptPath]`).